# Update Angular and its dependencies via CLI the proper way

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using Angular 8 and I'm facing most of the time an issue like below with incompatible peer dependencies. I'm wondering what's the best way to do?

`ng update --all`

> Package "ngx-cookie-service" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=4.2.0", would install "9.0.0-next.5").
>
> Package "ngx-cookie-service" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" (requires ">=4.2.0", would install "9.0.0-next.5").
>
> Package "ngx-cookie-service" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires ">=4.2.0", would install "9.0.0-next.5").
>
> Package "@auth0/angular-jwt" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires ">=6.0.0", would install "9.0.0-next.5").

What I do is forcing the update `ng update --all --force` but I'm sure there is a better way to do it. When I force update I need to change the TypeScript version in packages.json file. The version is often too "advanced"

Sometimes updating dependencies one by one with `ng update @angular/material` for example works (not all the time).

Any idea?

Comment: It seems that NPM's semver implementation doesn't consider `9.0.0-next.5` to be `>=4.2.0` or `>=6.0.0`. You can see this by playing with e.g. https://semver.npmjs.com/. But without `--next=true`, [`ng update`](https://angular.io/cli/update) shouldn't update to the pre-release version.

Comment: Thanks, @jonsharpe. I don't use the next parameter.  Weird that it tries to install a next version though. Even if I try `ng update @angular/material --next=false` I receive the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open bug in the Angular CLI.

See the issue here: [ng update @angular/cli installs angular 8.2.0-next.0](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14980)